# "IN" support for joins

Tags: pentaho, clickhouse

We're trying to connect **Pentaho BI** to **ClickHouse** and sometimes **Pentaho** generates queries as such:

```sql
select
...
from
date_dimension_table,
fact_table,
other_dimension_table
where
fact_table.fact_date = date_dimension_table.date
and date_dimension_table.calendar_year = 2019
and date_dimension_table.month_name in ('April', 'June', ...)
and fact_table.other_dimension_id = other_dimension_table.id
and other_dimension_table.code in ('code1', 'code2', ...)
group by
date_dimension_table.calendar_year,
date_dimension_table.month_name,
other_dimension_table.code;
```

It produces **ClickHouse** error: **Code: 403, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression, got (code AS c2) IN ('code1', 'code2', ...). Supported syntax: JOIN ON Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) [AND Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...)...] (version 19.15.3.6 (official build))**

Engines used for tables: fact_table - **MergeTree**, both dimensions - **TinyLog**.

Thus, questions:

1. Can this problem be solved by changing **table engines**? Unfortunately, we can't change query, it's autogenerated.
2. If not, are there any plans for supporting **joins** with **in** clause in **ClickHouse** in the nearest future?

Thanx.

Comment: could you provide the full exception message not excerpt & version of CH?

Comment: ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 403, host: ..., port: 8123; Code: 403, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression, got (code AS c2) IN ('code1', 'code2', ...). Supported syntax: JOIN ON Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) [AND Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...)...] (version 19.15.3.6 (official build))

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed beginning with [ClickHouse release v20.3.2.1, 2020-03-12](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats_new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v20-3-2-1-2020-03-12) (see [Issue 7314](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7314)), so you need to upgrade CH.

! Don't forget to check all backward-incompatible changes (see [changelog](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/whats_new/changelog/)).

---

Let's reproduce this problem on CH 19.15.3 revision 54426 to get the error you described:

```sh
Received exception from server (version 19.15.3):
Code: 403. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Invalid expression for JOIN ON. Expected equals expression, got code IN ('code1', 'code2'). Supported syntax: JOIN ON Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) [AND Expr([table.]column, ...) = Expr([table.]column, ...) ...].
```

Now execute this query on the latest version of CH (20.3.7 revision 54433) to make sure that it works correctly:

```sh
docker pull yandex/clickhouse-server:latest

docker run -d --name ch_test_latest yandex/clickhouse-server:latest

docker exec -it ch_test_latest clickhouse-client

# create tables as described below
..

# execute test query
..
```

---

Test preparation:

```sql
create table date_dimension_table (
    date DateTime,
    calendar_year Int32,
    month_name String
) Engine = Memory;

create table fact_table (
    fact_date DateTime,
    other_dimension_id Int32
) Engine = Memory;

create table other_dimension_table (
    id Int32,
    code String
) Engine = Memory;
```

Test query:

```sql
SELECT 
    date_dimension_table.calendar_year, 
    date_dimension_table.month_name, 
    other_dimension_table.code
FROM date_dimension_table
    ,fact_table
    ,other_dimension_table
WHERE (fact_table.fact_date = date_dimension_table.date) 
    AND (date_dimension_table.calendar_year = 2019) 
    AND (date_dimension_table.month_name IN ('April', 'June')) 
    AND (fact_table.other_dimension_id = other_dimension_table.id) 
    AND (other_dimension_table.code IN ('code1', 'code2'))
GROUP BY 
    date_dimension_table.calendar_year, 
    date_dimension_table.month_name, 
    other_dimension_table.code
```